# How to set required constants for methods?

Tags: java, methods, types, arguments, required

I am creating a method called setState and I want to use binary operators for it, but I want to create something to check if the passed argument is a constant defined in the class:

```
public static final int STATE1 = 0b1;
public static final int STATE2 = 0b10;
public static final int STATE3 = 0b100;
public void setState(int stateType, boolean state){
    if(state){
        this.state |= stateType;
    }else{
        this.state &= ~stateType;
    }
 }
```

So when I type setState(10, false) it will say: Wrong argument type, found x, required y

Comment: What is the type of `this.state` ?

Comment: It's integer, the class variable: private int state;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only want stateType to be one of STATE1, STATE2, or STATE3?
You could use an enum defined in that class. Something like:

```
public class MyClass{
    public enum State{
        STATE1 (0b1),
        STATE2(0b10),
        STATE3(0b100);

      public final int value;
      State(int value){
        this.value = value;
      }
    }

   public void setState(State stateType, boolean state){
    if(state){
        this.state |= stateType.value;
    }else{
        this.state &= ~stateType.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

One way to check a value against a group of allowed values is a `Set<Integer>` that contains all the allowed values. You can construct such set in a static constructor of the class, i.e.

```
private static final Set<Integer> allowedState = new HashSet<Integer>();
static {
    allowedState.add(STATE1);
    allowedState.add(STATE2);
    allowedState.add(STATE3);
}
```

Now you can check if the state passed to you is valid by verifying that `allowedState` contains `stateType`:

```
if (!allowedState.contains(stateType)) {
    // Throw an exception
}
```

To ensure that the allowedState set is immutable use `Collcetions.unmodifiableSet()`. Modifier `final` only ensures that the reference cannot be redinded to another object.

However, an approach based on raw `int` constants is *not* idiomatic to Java. A better way to achieve the same effect would be wrapping the states in an `enum` ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)), which would make sure that only a valid constant could be passed to your `setState` method:

```
public enum State {
    STATE1(0b1)
,   STATE2(0b10)
,   STATE3(0b100);

    private final int bitMask;
    State(int bitMask) { this.bitMask = bitMask; }
    public int getBitMask() { return bitMask; }
}
```

Comment: Or even better, use an `enum`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Absolutely. That was the second part of my answer - I was in the process of typing it up.

Comment: Very useful information, I am new in Java and here so I will take a look on this